# Python - delete old files

Tags: python

I'm somewhat new to python and have been trying to figure this out on my own but only getting bits and pieces so far.  Basically i'm looking for a script that will recursively search a directory and it's sub-directories and delete files that are at least 24 hours old but not alter the directories.
Any advice or examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted so far and what does it do wrong?

Comment: Let's see the bits and pieces, perhaps we can help glue the together?

Comment: You can't delete files from a directory without altering the directory.

Answer (score 38):

This uses the [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) method to recursively search a directory. For each file, it checks the modified date with [os.path.getmtime](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) and compares that with [datetime.now](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) (the current time). [datetime.timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) is constructed to create a timedelta of 24 hours.

It searches the directory os.path.curdir which is the current directory when the script is invoked. You can set `dir_to_search` to something else, e.g. a parameter to the script.

```
import os
import datetime

dir_to_search = os.path.curdir
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
   for file in filenames:
      curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
      file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
      if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(hours=24):
          os.remove(curpath)
```

Comment: how can I modify this when I want to delete the old files and save the new one even if it was generated a minute ago.

Answer (score 7):

If you need it to check all files in all directories recursively, something like this ought to do:

```
import os, time

path = "/path/to/folder"
def flushdir(dir):
    now = time.time()
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        fullpath = os.path.join(dir, f)
        if os.stat(fullpath).st_mtime < (now - 86400):
            if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
                os.remove(fullpath)
            elif os.path.isdir(fullpath):
                flushdir(fullpath)

flushdir(path)
```

Comment: how can I modify this when I want to delete the old files and save the new one and if its generated a minute ago