# Zipfile not writing data

Tags: python, logging, zip, python-zipfile

I have tried to zip log files that I have created, but nothing is written!
Code:

```
    def del_files():
        '''Adapted from answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217196/python-delete-old-files by jterrace'''
        dir_to_search = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'log')
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
            for file in filenames:
                curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                log(curpath)
                if curpath != path:
                    log("Archiving old log files...")
                    with zipfile.ZipFile("log_old.zip", "w") as ZipFile:
                        ZipFile.write(curpath)
                        ZipFile.close()
                        log("archived")
```

Comment: Are you hitting the if condition? Does an empty zipfile show up?

Comment: It has a wierd folder hierachy `\Users\*User*\Documents\GitHub\Game\log` and nothing inside the log folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you are overwriting the output zip file on each iteration:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("log_old.zip", "w") as ZipFile:
```

mode `"w"` means to create a new file, or truncate an existing file. Probably you mean to append to the zip file, in which case it can be opened for append by using mode `"a"`. Or you could open the zip file outside of the outer for loop.

Your code should result in `log_old.zip` containing a single file - the last one found by `os.walk()`.

Opening the archive outside of the main loop is better since the file will only be opened once, and it will be closed automatically because of the context manager (`with`):

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("log_old.zip", "w") as zf:
    dir_to_search = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'log')
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
        for file in filenames:
            curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            zf.write(curpath)
```

Comment: When I used this, it resulted in a zipfile with a folder hierachy like this: `Users\*User*\Documents\GitHub\Game\log` and had 1 file. I want to archive all my files except the one being written to

Comment: From which directory did you execute the above code? It should only archive those files contained in the `log` subdirectory of the current directory, with the archive being written to the current directory. That means that you must have run it from `\Users\*USER*\Documents\GitHub\Game\log_old.zip\Users\Cael\Documents\GitHub\Gam‌​e`.