# How do I delete a specified number of files in a directory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reduce the number of files in a folder or rather remove a specified number of files from the folder.
I'd appreciate simple solutions likely limited around my code below, which definitely is not working and wrong.

```
files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    for file in range(11):
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Which files do you want to delete? the first n files (when sorted alphabetically)?

Comment: @Zion
Try the solution given by `jterrace` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217196/python-delete-old-files

Comment: You should make clear what is going wrong with your code. And `os.listdir()[:10]` (or similar) might be a good starter.

Comment: @Felix Yes the first N files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to iterate correctly in the range:

```
files = os.listdir('path/to/your/folder')
for file in files[:11]:
    os.remove(file)
```

in this way you are iterating through a list containing the first 11 files.

If you want to remove random files, you can use:

```
from random import sample

files = os.listdir('path/to/your/folder')
for file in sample(files,11):
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and it worked. I simply edited the code to include a filepath and referenced it in the os.listdir(filepath). Only challenge I noticed is sorting the files alphabetically or numerically.

Comment: Nice! accept the answer if you're satisfied with the outcome

Comment: A little heads up, I had to use `os.remove('path/to/your/folder/'+file)` for python to find the files

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I also did a bit of digging and applying solutions from your contributions. Here is what I got. The sorting was via creation time which was more logical for the task.

```
import os
import re

filepath = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(filepath)
files = sorted(files,key=os.path.getmtime)
for file in files[:11]:
    os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os

files = os.listdir(r'C:/testdeletefolder')
fileslist=[]
for file in files:
    print file
    fileslist.append(file)

for i in range(0,2):
    os.remove(fileslist[i])
```

But ensure that you if condition to not to delete the python file which has code.this will delete 2 files you can change the counter in range

Comment: `os.listdir` already returns a list of files. You are iterating this list to create another list.